# Multiple package with exporter in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to get familiar with Perl exporter, the issue i am facing is whatever I try I cannot use exporter with modules containing multiple packages in it. What am I missing below?

```
MyModule.pm

use strict;
use warnings;

package Multipackage1;
use Exporter;
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT = qw(test1);

sub test1 {

  print "First package\n";

}

1;

package Multipackage2;
use Exporter;
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT = qw(test2);

sub test2 {

   print "Second package\n";

}

1;

package Multipackage3;
use Exporter;
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(test3);

sub test3 {

   print "Third package\n";

}

1;


MyMainFile.pl

#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use Multipackage;
use Multipackage qw(test3);

print "Calling first package:\n";
test1();
print "Calling second package:\n";
test2();
print "Calling third package:\n";
test3();
```

I getting test1 is not part of the main package.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and the Perl tag. This is a very nice first question. :)

Comment: thnq very thrilled to b part of it..may b shld have been apart a lot sooner.

Comment: Just one thing: we prefer it when people write full sentences and words here. There are a lot of professional developers here, and a lot of this is used in a work context. Please take your time and use punctuation and stuff. :)

Comment: Okay, sure from now I will.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) calls [require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html), which looks for a file with the package name (with `/` for `::` and + `.pm`).

So `require` the actual file with packages instead and then [import](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/import.html) from packages.

**main.pl**

```
use warnings;
use strict;

require MyModule;

import Multipackage1;
import Multipackage2;
import Multipackage3 qw(test3);

print "Calling first package:\n";
test1();
print "Calling second package:\n";
test2();
print "Calling third package:\n";
test3();
```

In the `MyModule.pm`, place each package in its own block to provide scope for lexical variables, since [package](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/package.html) doesn't do that, or use `package Pack { ... }` [since v5.14](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta.html#Syntactical-Enhancements). There is no need for all those `1`s, and you may pull `use Exporter;` out of the blocks.

Output

```
Calling first package:
First package
Calling second package:
Second package
Calling third package:
Third package
```

Better yet, replace `our @ISA = qw(Exporter);` with `use Exporter qw(import);` for

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package Multipackage1 {
    use Exporter qw(import);
    our @EXPORT = qw(test1);

    sub test1 { print "First package\n" }
}
...
1;
```

with the same output.

Note that putting multiple packages in one file is normally not needed and not done.